# Как переделать метод, что-бы записывать в список созданные обьекты (сидения в кинотеатре) а не слитые строки и потом их сравнивать внутри списка?

Tags: java, ооп

```
public List buyTickets(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
        System.out.print("Ряд: ");
        String exactRange = in.nextLine();
            if (exactRange.equals("stop")) {
                break;
            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(exactRange) <= this.range) {
                System.out.print("Место: ");
                String exactSeat = in.nextLine();
                if(Integer.parseInt(m) <= this.seat) {
                    if (listOfPlaces.size() == 0) {
                        listOfPlaces.add(exactRange + exactSeat);
                        System.out.println("Спасибо за покупку");
                    } else {
                        int i = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            if (listOfPlaces.get(i).equals(exactRange + exactSeat)) {
                                System.out.println("Такое место занято!");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (i == listOfPlaces.size()) {
                            System.out.println("Спсибо за покупку");
                            listOfPlaces.add(exactRange + exactSeat);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Некоректный ввод");
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Некоректный ввод");
            }
    }
    return  listOfPlaces;
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно создать объект, который будет инкапсулировать вашу логику, и работать будете уже с ним.

Comment: Я создаю обьект с двумя параметрами и ложу его в ArrayList. Потом создаю новый такой же обьект только с другими параметрами и сравниваю его через equals с тем что лежит в листе. Мне нужно что-бы  при сравнении обьектов с одинаковыми параметрами выдавало true, но оно говорит что обьекты разные

Comment: Метод List.contains использует метод equals объектов для сравнения. Переопределите метод в Вашем объекте.